# How can I use async/await in a es6 javascript class?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, ecmascript-6

So I'm trying to make a function of a class I made async, but webpack gives me an error when compiling the class.

My code would be something like this:

```
class MyClass {

   constructor(apiService) {
       this._apiService = apiService;
   }

   async updateInformation() {
       await this._apiService.updateInformation();
       // .. do more stuff I have to do 
   }
}
```

The error that webpack gives me is:

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token
```

(The Unexpected token points to the 'u' after async)

Comment: what is your bundling/transpiler setup?  babel6, webpack...

Comment: `async/await` is not part of ES6, so it won't run in environments that (only) support ES6. You need to convert it do ES6 code first (e.g. using Babel or regenerator).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, so I didn't realized that I hadn't added to my .babelrc file the stage-0 preset that includes async/await.

The code works just fine.

EDIT: As RGraham says, stage-3

Comment: `stage-0` is only for strawman proposals. It includes lots of unfinalized behavior and is *definitely not* ES6. If you wanted to do this via a Babel preset, it would be [stage-3](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-3/)

Answer (score 0):

`async/await` is part of *ES7* proposal. SO you need to use `babel/traceur` to compile your code to ES6/ ES5

Comment: ES7 is already finalized (meaning, no new features are going to be added). `async/await` comes in a future version, earliest next year.