# Async function inside a class

Tags: javascript, node.js

I get this error when I try to run an async function described in a class

**masterClass.js**

```
class MasterClass{

  async function updateData(a, b){
    let [ res1, res2 ] = await Promise.all(call1, call2);
    return  [ res1, res2 ]
  }

}
```

**test.js**

```
const MasterClass =  require('./MasterClass.js')
let m = new MasterClass()
m.updateData(a, b)
```

**Error**

```
async function updateData(a, b){
                 ^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Comment: `function` is not needed.

Comment: If I delete the "function" keyword I get TypeError: MasterClass is not a constructor

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36847282/how-can-i-use-async-await-in-a-es6-javascript-class

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You dont need `function` as pointed out by @dfsq in the comments

Then you have to use `module.exports` or `export` to exposed  your class as a module.

masterclass.js

```
module.exports = class MasterClass{

  async updateData(a, b){
    let [ res1, res2 ] = await Promise.all(call1, call2);
    return  [ res1, res2 ]
  }

}
```