# react js async function in a class

Tags: reactjs

I currently have a function called resetThenSet like so

```
resetThenSet = (id, arrayId, title) => {
  let size = [...this.state[arrayId]]
  blah blah blah
}
```

This resetthenSet method is called from my render method like so:

```
        <Dropdown
          title="Size"
          arrayId="selectProduct"
          list={this.state.selectProduct}
          resetThenSet={this.resetThenSet}
        />
```

Everything works.  I need to use async to be able to have another method inside of there await.  So I switch the resetThenset to this:

```
async resetThenSet(id, arrayId, title){
  let size = [...this.state[arrayId]]
  //blah blah blah
}
```

This gives me an error in my console.

```
Invalid argument passed as callback. Expected a function. Instead received: [object Promise]
```

This appears to be something related to scope so I figured I would just add binding for it:

```
this.resetThenSet = resetThenSet.bind(this);
```

This gives me the error

```
resetThenSet is not defined
```

Is there a simple way to change a fat arrow function to be an async function in react?

I checked this and it didn't help:
[How can I use async/await in a es6 javascript class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36847282/how-can-i-use-async-await-in-a-es6-javascript-class)

Comment: `this.resetThenSet = this.resetThenSet.bind(this);`. Also, consider checking this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48044643/4875631

Comment: You can avoid binding by using arrow functions syntax as well. 
async resetThenSet = (id, arrayId, title) => {
  let size = [...this.state[arrayId]]
  //blah blah blah
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.resetThenSet = this.resetThenSet.bind(this);
```

Try this, as you were binding to an undeclared function. That's why it was throwing error

You can read more about "why to bind the function to this"
https://medium.freecodecamp.org/this-is-why-we-need-to-bind-event-handlers-in-class-components-in-react-f7ea1a6f93eb

Answer (score 2):

```
class youDidntTellUs extends Component {

async resetThenSet(id, arrayId, title){
let size = [...this.state[arrayId]]
  //blah blah blah
}

render(){
return (
  <Dropdown
      title="Size"
      arrayId="selectProduct"
      list={this.state.selectProduct}
      resetThenSet={() => this.resetThenSet()}
    />
...
```

Comment: Avoid passing new closures to subcomponents. every time the parent component renders, a new function is created and passed to the input.

This is a React component, this would automatically trigger it to re-render, regardless of whether its other props have actually changed.